# Android Right and Left Swipe Gestures handling

Tags: android, scrollview, swipe-gesture

so I tried Zala's code for handling the gestures from this question [android how to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures), it works but the problem is my component is inside a scrollview so the gestures sometimes are detected sometimes not, I tried few different codes to solve this scrollview issue still the same behavior.
Anyone could help please !

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330187/gesture-detection-and-scrollview-issue

Comment: I have seen it still dosen't work for me

Comment: then try scrollview .setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return false;
            }
        });

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect swipe using onTouchListener in ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141264/detect-swipe-using-ontouchlistener-in-scrollview)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                        downX = event.getX();}
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
                        upX = event.getX();

                        float deltaX = downX - upX;

                        if(Math.abs(deltaX)>0){
                            if(deltaX>=0){
                                swipeToRight();
                                return true;
                            }else{
                                swipeToLeft();
                                return  true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
});
```

Comment: the swipe is not on the scrollview, its on a chart inside the scrollview

Comment: implement same event for chart view as well

Comment: It trigger the swipe left event when i am doing vertical scroll.

Comment: This will conflict with scroll view controller like recycleview etc.